# Split array of multiple data types into different arrays

Tags: json, postgresql

I have data available in postgres database on which I need to run a BI tool to have some aggregational information. Unfortunately the data is structured in the weirdest way.  I have the example json column to work with:

```
{"products": ["345661C1-2665-4870-9649-803B20A4B579", 1, "FE719978-253F-4763-B1B7-648B9988C5BF", 2, "F66FE491-AC06-49DD-987B-0B88CB49CEB7", 2, "5628A5A4-6030-459D-96F3-32D3C04B7F80", 3, "2B8DAE11-5D60-4DB7-901B-0CCBA7D9418C", 1]}
```

I do realize the products array itself is not in the correct postgres syntax neither are the string literals.

Ideally I have a query resulting in this:

| Product | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 345661C1-2665-4870-9649-803B20A4B579 | 1 |
| FE719978-253F-4763-B1B7-648B9988C5BF | 2 |
| F66FE491-AC06-49DD-987B-0B88CB49CEB7 | 2 |
| 5628A5A4-6030-459D-96F3-32D3C04B7F80 | 3 |
| 2B8DAE11-5D60-4DB7-901B-0CCBA7D9418C | 1 |

Is this possible with postgres? I was looking for

- a function to split arrays based on data type
- a function to remove elements based on odd/even index

I would always look for a solution with code but the BI tool is the only one whitelisted for this database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will let you to unnest data from one record, or a few/all records at once

```sql
-- sample schema
create table datatable (
  id int primary key,
  data jsonb
);
-- some data
insert into datatable values
(1, '{"products": ["FE719978-253F-4763-B1B7-648B9988C5BF", 2, "F66FE491-AC06-49DD-987B-0B88CB49CEB7", 2]}'),
(2, '{"products": ["345661C1-2665-4870-9649-803B20A4B579", 1]}'),
(3, '{"products": ["5628A5A4-6030-459D-96F3-32D3C04B7F80", 3, "2B8DAE11-5D60-4DB7-901B-0CCBA7D9418C", 1]}');
-- select
WITH pre AS (
  SELECT *, RANK()over(ORDER BY id) AS rk FROM datatable
   JOIN jsonb_array_elements_text(data->'products') WITH ORDINALITY AS v(v) ON TRUE
  WHERE id = 3 -- for specific record id
  -- remove/modify the WHERE clause for all / some records at once
)
SELECT pre1.v AS product, pre2.v::INT AS amount
 FROM pre AS pre1
 JOIN pre AS pre2
   ON pre1.ordinality % 2 = 1
  AND pre2.ordinality = 1 + pre1.ordinality 
  AND pre1.rk = pre2.rk;
```

Comment: This just works out of the box, and the split by id is exactly what I needed afterwards!

Answer (score 1):

This feels a bit hackish (and will fail if your arrays aren't in a "key/value" list format), but you could use `WITH ORDINALITY` to keep track of the index of each element and group by `ordinality / 2` (to regroup consecutive elements together):

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH data(arr) AS (
  VALUES (ARRAY['345661C1-2665-4870-9649-803B20A4B579', '1', 'FE719978-253F-4763-B1B7-648B9988C5BF', '2', 'F66FE491-AC06-49DD-987B-0B88CB49CEB7', '2', '5628A5A4-6030-459D-96F3-32D3C04B7F80', '3', '2B8DAE11-5D60-4DB7-901B-0CCBA7D9418C', '1'])
)
SELECT (ARRAY_AGG(unnest ORDER BY ordinality))[1] AS product, (ARRAY_AGG(unnest ORDER BY ordinality))[2] AS amount
FROM data
CROSS JOIN LATERAL UNNEST(arr) WITH ORDINALITY
GROUP BY (ordinality-1) / 2; /* ordinality is 1-based, hence the -1 */
```

| product | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 345661C1-2665-4870-9649-803B20A4B579 | 1 |
| FE719978-253F-4763-B1B7-648B9988C5BF | 2 |
| F66FE491-AC06-49DD-987B-0B88CB49CEB7 | 2 |
| 5628A5A4-6030-459D-96F3-32D3C04B7F80 | 3 |
| 2B8DAE11-5D60-4DB7-901B-0CCBA7D9418C | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements_text() WITH ORDINALITY` to get the elements of the JSON array as a table along with their ordinality. Then aggregate by grouping every two ordinalities. Use a `FILTER` clause to separate the odd from the even ordinalities to get the right values in the right column.

```
CREATE TABLE elbat
AS
SELECT '{"products": ["345661C1-2665-4870-9649-803B20A4B579", 1, "FE719978-253F-4763-B1B7-648B9988C5BF", 2, "F66FE491-AC06-49DD-987B-0B88CB49CEB7", 2, "5628A5A4-6030-459D-96F3-32D3C04B7F80", 3, "2B8DAE11-5D60-4DB7-901B-0CCBA7D9418C", 1]}'::jsonb AS nmuloc;

SELECT max(jae.e) FILTER (WHERE jae.o % 2 = 1) AS product,
       max(jae.e) FILTER (WHERE jae.o % 2 = 0)::integer AS amount
       FROM elbat t
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(t.nmuloc->'products') WITH ORDINALITY jae
                                                                                               (e,
                                                                                                o)
       GROUP BY (jae.o + 1) / 2
       ORDER BY min(jae.o);
```

But you're lucky Postgres is so mighty and sophisticated that such a thing is even possible. What you really should do is stopping to abuse JSON and go the relational way. Have a table for the products like the one you want to produce from the beginning and don't store that as JSON (and even there it's the worst possible way you do that -- why an array where even elements have other meanings that odd ones, at least use an array of objects with ID an amount).

Comment: Thank you for showing me the WITH ORDINALITY functionality! I do realise the data is not as it should be but I don't have access to the application code, I only have the database available for reporting